# how to get facebook session in more than two pages using PHP fb api?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

i need a facebook session. in my first page code is

```
session_start();
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('....', '.....');
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/fb/test.php');
echo "<a href='".$helper->getLoginUrl()."'>login</a>";
```

i am getting session to test.php

```
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('.....', '....');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/fb/test.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}

if($session) {
//some code here
}
```

i want to get this session to another page next.php
is that my coding way is correct?
how i get the same session in another page?

Comment: Store the Facebook session into the PHP session …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer.
add to test.php

```
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
```

in next.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('...', '...');

$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
```

Answer (score 0):

session can be accessible from any pages...

```
if($session) {

        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
}
```

Now you can access  $_SESSION['FBID'] from any pages..

Comment: how to get $session i another page??

Comment: in $_SESSION variable only [FBRLH_state] is getting